# How to add multiple icon to the options in react-select?

Tags: reactjs, react-select

Attempts to add multiple icon to option in react-select. I imported icons from the react-feather

**HERE IS MY CODE :** and getting error `<Star size={14} /> <Star size={14} />`

```
import React from "react";
import Select from "react-select";
import { Star } from "react-feather";
const Options = [
  {
    label: "Stars",
    options: [
      { value: 1, label: <Star size={14} /> },
      { value: 2, label: <Star size={14} /> <Star size={14} />},
      { value: 3, label: <Star size={14} /> <Star size={14} /> <Star size={14} />},
    ],
  },
];
const formatGroupLabel = (data) => (
  <div className="d-flex justify-content-between align-center">
    <strong>
      <span>{data.label}</span>
    </strong>
    <span>{data.options.length}</span>
  </div>
);
class Test extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <FormGroup>
        <Label>Илэрхийлэлийн түвшин</Label>
        <Select
          defaultValue={Options[0]}
          options={Options}
          formatGroupLabel={formatGroupLabel}
        />
      </FormGroup>
    );
  }
}
export default Test;
```

Comment: Hi, does the error just say `<Star size={14} /> <Star size={14} />` or is there more? If there's more please post it so we can better help you.

Comment: hello sir, here is error: JSX expressions must have one parent element.ts(2657)

Comment: oh im dumb as hell, i just added div container and it's done

Answer (score 0):

Check this one, in [react-select](https://react-select.com/components) it accepts a prop called components, where you can configure your Options

```
import Select, { components } from "react-select";
const { Option } = components;

 const CustomOption = props => (
  <Option {...props}>
    // your custom icons
    {props.data.label}
  </Option>
);


 <Select
    defaultValue={options[0]}
    options={options}
    components={{ Option: CustomOption }}
  />
```

Comment: hello sir my brain just ded last night xD, i just added div container and it's done

Comment: Cool happy to help :)

Comment: @Learner thanks for this. Do you know how we can get the icon to display in the main box after selecting the item? This seems to only handle the icons for options in the dropdown menu.